# Laravel - what to use as session ID?

Tags: php, laravel

Im getting into laravel for backend purposes. I've noticed that there are several ID's provided by Laravel and I have no idea which one to use. When using "$request->session()->token();" it shows me an ID called _token. Then there's a Cookie token called laravel_session and apparently a 3rd one, consisting of numbers only, "session()->getId()". Which one is the one to use now?

Comment: You just read and write to the session, you don't need to know what the session ID is. The PHP constant `SID` will always give it to you.

Comment: Im using AngularJS in the frontend so I need to set the SessionID at the login. My question however is, which one?

Comment: Your frontend does not need to know the session ID at all, that's got nothing to do with the frontend regardless of the framework you're using.

Comment: Then how am I gonna verify SQL Queries that are meant for a specific user only?

Comment: @KonstantinSchlegel I think you need a tutorial on authentication and a little bit of information on frontend versus backend. Seems like you're mixing up your logic. The frontend doesn't do any SQL queries nor does it handle sessions at all. Best you google some tuts, there are **many** available.

Comment: I know that the frontend doesn't do that. But when logging into my account I need it to create a Session ID that I send to the backend with each request so that it can verify which account it's coming from. Right?

Comment: Everything to do with sessions is done by the server; you can't trust anything that comes from Javascript. The browser automatically sends the session ID in cookies when it talks to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`session()->getId()` is the correct session ID.

`$request->session()->token()` returns the CSRF token, not the session ID.
The `laravel_session` cookie may be encrypted if you're using the middleware.

Comment: How come $request->session()->token() 's ID doesn't show up when using ->all()?

Comment: Is the CSRF token in the request or in the headers? `$request->all` does not display headers. It **only displays the query params**

Comment: `request()->all()` displays **all form input including query parameters** not just query parameters. Though, I'm not seeing the relevance there, that's got nothing to do with the question. `request->session()->token()` isn't a collection and even so, this question is bogus and this answer encourages using Laravel very poorly.

Comment: @snh that's a load! This is a straightforward answer to how to get the session ID. If it's such a bad thing to get the session ID why don't you submit a PR to the framework to make it a protected method?

Comment: To your comment on all form input, you are correct and I stand corrected.

Comment: It's not a bad thing to get the session ID at all. You've completely missed the nail on this one. OP clearly has no experience with authentication nor session handlers, that's the issue I'm addressing. Sure your answer addresses the original question, but the original question is absolute bollocks because that's **not** how requests are supposed to operate and you're answering regardless of that fact, influencing people to utilise Laravel in a very poor manner.

Comment: With regard to the PR, I haven't got a clue what tangent you're going off on there. I stated how things currently are, not how I want them to be.